# Prolog - Redo after failed if-statement leads to uninstantiated variable?

Tags: prolog

Solved: Read the responses, seems to be a formatting issue. Put brackets around line 4.

I'm trying to use the if->then;else in prolog to sum up only the even integers in a list. I'm just trying to skip numbers if they are not even. Here is my code below.

```
sum_even([], 0).
sum_even([H|T], Sum):-
    sum_even(T, Temp),
    even(H) -> Sum is H + Temp; Sum is Temp.

even([]).
even(Num):-
    0 is Num mod 2.
```

The problem is, when even(H) fails, it calls a 'redo' (not sure what this means) on the line above which then leads to Temp being unsubstantiated? So Sum is Temp fails and then the whole thing fails. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing parentheses around the *if-then-else* construct. Operator precedence makes the *if* part be `sum_even(T, Temp), even(H)` in your code. Try instead:

```
sum_even([], 0).
sum_even([H|T], Sum):-
    sum_even(T, Temp),
    (even(H) -> Sum is H + Temp; Sum is Temp).
```